# Visual Studio: find most called method in a project

Tags: visual-studio

I'd like to find my most called method in a nodejs project, is there any way to see that with visual code (or a descending list of method sorted by call/references?)

I know that I can put the cursor on a method name and press Shift+F12 to "Go to References", but that's not what I am asking.

Comment: nodejs *functions* are not that visible.  Google "nodejs profiler" to get ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant if I understand correctly you suggest it's not an option to gather this information without running a profiler?